# Writing shell scripts using pipes

Tags: shell, pipe, md5, cut, tee

I'm interested in writing a shell script which will tell me whether a file has been altered or changed, through the use of the MD5 checksumming algorithm.

I'm utilising the following line or code, however don't quite understand how pipes are being utilised in the example. I believe this is comparing one file to another saved file, however would love any form of explanation on how this works with the use of the cut and tee commands. Thanks in advance!

```
md5=`md5sum ${FILE} | cut -d" " -f1 | tee "${SAVEDIR}/${FILE}.md5"`
```

Comment: sorry, what functionality do you want to achieve? in my understanding it's just `md5` the file, get the checksum without the filename, and save it to a `file` as well as a `variable`. nothing special. There's no comparision as you said

Answer (score 1):

this code is just one way to do the following:

- get the md5 checksum via *md5sum* of your file given in the variable and pipe it to
- *cut* which takes the first line of the string submitted to it and reads it until a space occurs. then it pipes this to
- *tee* which simply puts the string to the given folder and file.

please have a look at the man pages of all commands/programs since the contain all information you need to understand their behaviour

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to change your below command:-

```
md5=`md5sum ${FILE} | cut -d" " -f1 | tee "${SAVEDIR}/${FILE}.md5"`
```

To

```
md5=$(md5sum ${FILE} | cut -d" " -f1 | tee "${SAVEDIR}/${FILE}.md5")
```

Because first one is considered old these days.

Now regarding `|`, in Unix/Linux environment we use this directive to redirect the out put of one command to other. The left most command always get first preference and execute first.

Now see below, you have total 3 commands here

First command to execute is

```
 md5=`md5sum ${FILE}
```

Once the above command execute its out put will be redirect to below command

```
 cut -d" " -f1 'output from  md5=`md5sum ${FILE}'
```

So in the above `cut` command will work on the out put from the first command.

Now finally the out put from   `cut -d" " -f1 'output from  md5=md5sum ${FILE}'`
 will be redirect/feed to   command `tee "${SAVEDIR}/${FILE}.md5")` and this will generate the final output and that output will be stored in variable `md5`

Hope this will help you.